# Output to specific containers based on what button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project that current generates random strings to a container when a button is clicked. What I am now trying to do is this. I will include 4 more buttons on the page, and when each one is clicked, it will display specific strings for that user button. I am fine with the if/else logic and that, but I am not familiar with jQuery and am fairly rusty on my HTML. Here is what I have to start, which is the random strings. How can I have multiple containers to output to and reference different buttons on click in my if/else statements?

```
          function change_string()
          {
          var $container = $('.container');
          $container.html('');


              var myString= streams.home[myStringNo];
              var $myString= $('<div></div>');
          $myString.text('@' + myString.user + ': ' + myString.message + 'Generated:     ' + timeStamp);
              $myString.appendTo($container);
              myStringNo ++;

          };
```

Any help is appreciated as I am more familiar with the basic JS to generate the strings than how to actually activate based on button pushes and the container aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good use case for [HTML5 data attributes](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/). Check that link for more info on how to use them.  I would do something like this:

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><button data-target="#first">First</button></td>
            <td><button data-target="#second">Second</button></td>
            <td><button data-target="#third">Third</button></td>
            <td><button data-target="#fourth">Fourth</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="first" class="string-target"></div>
    <div id="second" class="string-target"></div>
    <div id="third" class="string-target"></div>
    <div id="fourth" class="string-target"></div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).text('Random String'); // Here's where your code for changing the random strings would go.
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle so you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/ah0zt2y4/

Comment: Maybe I am over complicating again. Would it be possible to, based on what button is clicked, contain replaceWith new array?

Comment: @jmcgui05, I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking, but no, you cannot replace a DOM element with an array.  Maybe you need to ask a new question.

Comment: @jmcgui05 glad I could help you out on your new question.  I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer here as well.  I know it wasn't quite what you were looking for, but it may help someone in the future.  Cheers